# HTML5 custom player not working with Soundcloud api uri

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, soundcloud

I am using a jQuery plugin which turns simple `<audio></audio>` into a set of different elements which are than controlled by javascript, basically creates a custom html5 player.
You can find a blog post on this plugin here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/04/responsive-touch-friendly-audio-player/
it explains this plugin in depth.

anyway, for some reason it is not working when I generate `src=""` for the player via     Soundcloud api. Basically I get song url from Soundcloud and than add it as src to the audio tag.

The issue is that once page is loaded it says `src="unknown"` (or something along these lines)

Here is HTML markup which demonstrates use of both Soundcloud api and Custom player plugin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/player.css">

</head>
<body>

<audio id="audio-test" controls></audio>

<!-- Javascript/jQuery -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script src="/player.js"></script> <!-- /js/player.js -->

<script>
// Soundcloud
SC.initialize({
    client_id: '7a17129ba9cd5fff34f847e3539829b7'
});

SC.get("/tracks/81815566", {}, function(sound){
    $("#audio-test").attr("src", sound.uri + "/stream?client_id=7a17129ba9cd5fff34f847e3539829b7");
});

//Custom Player
$( function() { $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer(); } );
</script>

<!-- END Javascript/jQuery -->

</body>
</html>
```

And here are additional files that you may need to see player in full functionality:

**player.css** http://pastebin.com/HBUFvUw2 
**reset.css**  http://pastebin.com/jstmq0dB 
**player.js (the plugin)** http://pastebin.com/MKrUgRDF

---

**Or just download whole project from here:** http://www.filedropper.com/example_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem is the `/stream?client_id=...`. I got rid of the whole string and changed `sound.uri` to `sound.stream_url`, and it's now streaming (at least in Safari/FF OSX).

See [my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kS97M/5/). If this isn't working for you, let me know and we'll figure it out!

**EDIT**: I just tried it again and it isn't working now. Gimme a minute to figure it out.

**EDIT II**: Keeping the client-id but changing `sound.uri` to `sound.stream_url` seems to have fixed it. It seems the sound.uri link prompts a 301 redirect that the audio player can't follow, but sound.stream_url links directly to the media. See updated fiddle link.

Comment: The thing with that /strem?client_id... is that before I added it to url I was getting a 401 forbidden error on songs, so they wont play, The only way I managed to fix it was by adding that part to url. And I think jsfiddle is not working because Soundcloud sdk is not included. Furthermore, on its own (in a default player) it is working, but once I apply jQuery custom player plugin to audio element it says that src is undefended/unknown

Comment: Yeah figured that out all too quickly. I don't know how I got it to work without it - but the code i've got in the fiddle should work for you now.

Comment: The code provided in fiddle works fine with default browser player, but once I apply plugin to it, still does't work and says that it's "undefined" , do you have a dropbox account? I could add you to my project folder, that's where I host the player for now

Comment: I am assuming, that plugin is called before that src="" is actually aded to player, so that's why it thinks it is undefined, is there a way to first add src="" to audio tag and only after that call player.js plugin?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get to it, work has been killer today. What was the answer?

Comment: At the moment I had to change some bits in plugin code so it always sets audio type to mpeg3, and I manually added src="" to audio tag (so I had to get rid of api for now). Now I still can't get it to work with api, it just seems that when using api src="" is added to player after plugin is applied, therefore it shows src="undefined"